# Generate angular client code for swagger generated rest end points from yaml file through plugin

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor, swagger-codegen

I have a yaml file containing all the configuration to my rest end points for swagger document.

I am able to generate the `typescript-angular2` online from [swagger online editor](https://editor.swagger.io/) which is working fine.

But my requirement is to generate the client in a jenkins job or command prompt.

I heard that there is a jar from which I can generate that. is anybody tried that and generated typescript-angular2 client from swagger yaml file?

I have gone through the link and its different from what I look for [swagger java client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33354557/how-to-generate-java-client-code-for-swagger-rest-api-documentation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate java client code for swagger REST API documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33354557/how-to-generate-java-client-code-for-swagger-rest-api-documentation)

Comment: no that is different! its about the latest angular 2 client and generating from command through jars

Comment: The idea is the same - use Swagger Codegen. It's available as a JAR or via a REST API (http://generator.swagger.io).

Comment: I am able to do that from the online editor but unable to do that from command or using plugin. i need this to configure in jenkins so that it will automatically do on build success

Comment: What about the second answer on that question? Using curl and the generator endpoints, you can try it here: https://generator.swagger.io/ this is what the online editor does