# Trouble installing Swagger CodeGen

Tags: jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, swagger-codegen

I installed Swagger CodeGen using the command

```
npm install swagger-codegen -g
```

So I should have it installed, but there is some error/glitch going on. Everytime I enter

```
swagger-codegen -v
```

I get the following message

'swagger-codegen' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I have no idea what to do. How should I fix this? I am trying to follow a tutorial, but the instructor nevers shows how he installs programs.

Under GitHub, the instructions don't make sense

Prerequisites
If you're looking for the latest stable version, you can grab it directly from Maven.org (Java 7 runtime at a minimum):

```
wget http://central.maven.org/maven2/io/swagger/swagger-codegen-cli/2.3.1/swagger-codegen-cli-2.3.1.jar -O swagger-codegen-cli.jar

java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar help
```

For Windows users, you will need to install wget or you can use Invoke-WebRequest in PowerShell (3.0+), e.g.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile swagger-codegen-cli.jar http://central.maven.org/maven2/io/swagger/swagger-codegen-cli/2.3.1/swagger-codegen-cli-2.3.1.jar
```

Am I supposed to put those in the command line? tried that, didn't work

Comment: Run in windows Powershell

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Swagger Codegen is a Java app, so you must have Java installed.

There are two versions of Swagger Codegen - 2.x and 3.x. Use 3.x for `openapi: 3.0.0` definitions and 2.x for `swagger: '2.0'`.

### Installing Swagger Codegen CLI (Command-Line Version)

#### Windows

Download the compiled JAR file:

- Codegen 3.x JARs are here: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/io/swagger/codegen/v3/swagger-codegen-cli/
- Codegen 2.x JARs are here: http://central.maven.org/maven2/io/swagger/swagger-codegen-cli/

Look for the file named `swagger-codegen-cli-<version>.jar`, e.g. if you need v. 2.3.1:
http://central.maven.org/maven2/io/swagger/swagger-codegen-cli/2.3.1/swagger-codegen-cli-2.3.1.jar

[image: Swagger Codegen JAR file]

To run the codegen, use:

```
java -jar c:\path\to\swagger-codegen-cli-<version>.jar <args>
```

(You can rename `swagger-codegen-cli-<version>.jar` to `swagger-codegen-cli.jar` for simplicity.)

#### Mac

Install using Homebrew:

```
# Codegen 3.x
brew install swagger-codegen

# Codegen 2.x
brew install swagger-codegen@2
```

Then you can run the codegen as:

```
swagger-codegen <args>
swagger-codegen@2 <args>
```

If you don't have Homebrew, download the JAR file from Maven and run it as explained above for Windows.

### Alternatives to CLI Version

You can also:

- generate the server and client code from [Swagger Editor](http://editor.swagger.io) (it has an integrated codegen).
- call the online codegen using its [REST API](http://generator.swagger.io). ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33365276/113116))
- use the Maven plugin: [`swagger-codegen-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/modules/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin). The group ID is `io.swagger` for Codegen 2.x and `io.swagger.codegen.v3` for Codegen 3.x.

Comment: I am using a Windows. I downloaded the jar file, renamed it to     swagger-codegen-cli.jar on my command line,, just simply enter    java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar? When I do that I get the message 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: now when I type the command java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar I get Error: Unable to access jarfile swagger-codegen-cli.jar

Comment: Swagger Codegen is a Java app, so you need Java. Make sure to specify the path to `swagger-codegen-cli.jar` in your command.

Comment: ok, still new to this stuff. I know I go to environment variables, go to path add it there. Do I just add swagger-codegen-cli.jar to the path or does it have to be in a special format? entering java -jar C:\swagger-codegen-cli.jar doesn't work either, which is where my jar file is

Comment: You don't need to add JAR file paths to the `PATH`, just use the full path in the `java -jar path\to\jarfile` command. *"Doesn't work either"* - how exactly does it not work? What is the error message?

Comment: my jar file is under my C: section, so the only path I have to specify is just C:\...

Comment: I tried that, doesn't work, even if I specify the path so when I enter `java -jar C:\swagger-codegen-cli.jar` I still get the message Error: Unable to access jarfile C:\swagger-codegen-cli.jar

Comment: Try moving the JAR to a subfolder instead, e.g. `C:\codegen\`.

Comment: I created another folder called codegen and put my jar file in it so the command should be `java -jar C:\codegen\swagger-codegen-cli.jar`, still cannot access it

Comment: I decided to delete and redownload it, now when I type the command in I guess it works, it prints a large message that looks right, first part saying available languages, in the tutorial, the instructor entered `swagger-codegen --version` , I did that but still get 'swagger-codegen' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: ok, I got it working, the instructor is using a mac so commands are a bit different. had to enter `java -jar C:\swagger-codegen-cli-2.3.1.jar --version` thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

this module doesn't create an executable file when being installed via `npm install swagger-codegen -g`, that's why you see the error. Please see https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/README.md#prerequisites for installation instructions

Comment: I tried looking at that, but it is very confusing. I downloaded the entire zip file, not sure what to do with that. Under installation, I tried using those commands in the command line, but never worked