# Accessing the Swagger API's through Java instead of accessing manually

Tags: java, api, selenium, swagger

I want to access API's through Java code instead of doing manually everytime. 
Could not find a way to do this. As of now, I am using Java TestNG framework for my work project in Selenium Automation.

Here is the screenshot of API that I need to access:
https://ibb.co/1dmRd5G

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [swagger-codegen-maven-plugin](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/modules/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin)?

Comment: [How to generate Java client code for Swagger REST API documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33354557/113116)

Answer (score 0):

You can auto generate Java code for REST Api from swagger defination using Swagger Codegen.

This link might help [CodeGen sample](https://medium.com/@dewni.matheesha/automatic-code-generation-from-a-swagger-definition-for-a-rest-api-b2d080cffe09)